# I want to list my array and doesnt want to repeat same value

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I have array like below. And I want to list it in flatlist without repeat same object. I want to make if there is same object it should sum of the values of it.

```
array example = [ {id:1 name:'test1' price:15 }, {id:2 name:'test2' price:20 }, {id:1 name:'test1' price:15 } ];
```

Answer (score 0):

`Flatlist` **doesn't support filtering unique items**.

You have to filter the unique values before passing it to flatlist.

The easiest way to get unique values is to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#uniq).

```
for eg: const uniqData = _.uniq([{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
```

and then pass it to `flatlist`.

```
<Flatlist data={uniqData} />
```